# Clustering by distance in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a vector of integers which I wish to divide into clusters so that the distance between any two clusters is greater than a lower bound, and within any cluster, the distance between two elements is less than an upper bound.

For example, suppose we have the following vector:

1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 29, 32, 36

And set the aforementioned lower bound and upper bound to 19 and 9 respectively, the two vectors below should be a possible result:

1, 4, 5, 6, 9

29, 32, 36

---

Thanks to @flodel 's comments, I realized this kind of clustering may be impossible. So I would like to modify the questions a bit:

What are the possible clustering methods if I impose only the **between** cluster distance lower bound?
What are the possible clustering methods if I impose only the **within**  cluster distance upper bound?

Comment: What happens if there is a distance between the bounds?

Comment: Does your problem become infeasible if I add `20` to your vector? You can't have both conditions at the same time. In other words, are you looking for an algorithm that will tell you when the two conditions cannot be met, or were you not aware of that possibility? In which case you might have to rethink your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*What are the possible clustering methods if I impose only the between cluster distance lower bound?*

Hierarchical clustering with **single linkage**:

```
x <- c(1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 29, 32, 46, 55)
tree <- hclust(dist(x), method = "single")
split(x, cutree(tree, h = 19))

# $`1`
# [1] 1 4 5 6 9
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 29 32 46 55
```

---

*What are the possible clustering methods if I impose only the within cluster distance upper bound?*

Hierarchical clustering with **complete linkage**:

```
x <- c(1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 20, 26, 29, 32)
tree <- hclust(dist(x), method = "complete")
split(x, cutree(tree, h = 9))

# $`1`
# [1] 1 4 5 6 9
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 20
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 26 29 32
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple algorithm that will work, explained conceptually (implementation details omitted):

1. Ensure your list is sorted.
2. Place a "marker" between every pair of consecutive elements that are more than `lower_bound` apart.  These mark all the possible cluster boundaries.
3. Include a marker before the beginning of the list and after the end.
4. Go through pairs of markers in order, and for each pair `left_marker` and `right_marker`, check if the distance between the element immediately to the right of the `left_marker` and the element immediately to the left of the `right_marker` is less than `upper_bound` apart.
5. If the previous step ever returns false, the clustering is impossible.
6. Otherwise, the markers form the boundaries of the desired clusterings.

Applying this to your example, we get:

1. Sorted: 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 26, 29, 32
2. Markers: 1, 4, 5, 6, 9 | 26, 29, 32
3. Additional start/end markers: | 1, 4, 5, 6, 9 | 26, 29, 32 |
4. Check "upper bound" constraint: (9-1) = 8 < 9: TRUE; (32 - 26) = 6 < 9: TRUE
5. None of the comparisons returned false
6. Desired clustering: (1, 4, 5, 6, 9), (26, 29, 32)

---

**EDIT**: Original poster relaxed the conditions of the problem.

If you only want to satisfy the lower bound condition:

1. Ensure your list is sorted.
2. Place a marker between every pair of consecutive elements that are more than `lower_bound` apart.
3. Include a marker before the beginning and after the end.
4. These markers form the boundaries of the desired clustering.

The following gets you step 2 assuming your vector is already sorted:

```
# Given
vec <- c(1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 29, 32, 26)
lower_bound <- 19

f <- function(x) {
  return(vec[x+1] - vec[x] > lower_bound);
}
indices <- seq(length(vec)-1)
marker_positions <- Position(f, indices)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have up-voted your answer, it's very clear and helpful, but the question is looking for a practical approach in R, and if  existing functions or packages already can do it, a recommendation would be much appreciated. Also because the clustering on condition of both bounds may be impossible in some cases, I have edited the question a little, could you please have a look? Thank you! :)

Comment: Actually, perhaps I don't understand your original problem.  The distance between 9 and 26 is only 17, which is less than 19.  How is this supposed to be a correct clustering?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta But what if you add 20 to the list of numbers? Does your algorithm still be correct?

Comment: Yeah, it will yield no marker positions, so after doing step 3, the only markers you'll have are left of the start and right of the end, meaning, all the elements belong to one cluster equal to the entire original vector.