# Clustering a second vector according to a clustered first vector in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a vector that has been divided into two clusters (as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228737/clustering-by-distance-in-r)):

```
    x <- c(1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 29, 32, 46, 55)
    tree <- hclust(dist(x), method = "single")
    split(x, cutree(tree, h = 19))
    # $`1`
    # [1] 1 4 5 6 9
    #
    # $`2`
    # [1] 29 32 46 55
```

Now suppose I have another cluster of the same length, which I wish to divide into the same number of clusters by the same indices as x, take the following vector y as an example:

```
    set.seed(77)
    y = rnorm(9)
    y
    #[1] -0.54964  1.09105  0.63978  1.04258  0.16970  1.13780 -0.97055 -0.13183
    #[9]  0.14623
```

The desired result should be like this:

```
    # $`1`
    # [1] -0.54964  1.09105  0.63978  1.04258  0.16970
    #
    # $`2`
    # [1] 1.13780 -0.97055 -0.13183 0.14623
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you did for `x`:

```
split(y, cutree(tree, h = 19))
```

And since you are now using `cutree(tree, h = 19)` in multiple places, you might as well assign it to a variable:

```
groups <- cutree(tree, h = 19)
split(x, groups)
split(y, groups)
```